# Failing to match/search in an index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to search my index but using the documented `match` syntax fails.

Here is the result of

```
GET apm-7.6.2-transaction-000001/_search
{
  "_source": ["transaction.custom.campaign_name"],
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

returns

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 6,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
...
```

but when I try to filter the results and get only values, where the transaction.custom.campaign_name is at some specific value,

```
GET apm-7.6.2-transaction-000001/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "match" : { 
      "transaction.custom.campaign_name": "ca*"
    }
  }
}
```

I get zero hits:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Could anyone point me to the issue here?

thank you very much!

PS: Here is an example of a single hit, when math_all is used:

```
...
{
        "_index" : "apm-7.6.2-transaction-000001",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "8gX_B3IB6W5uorYBtJHZ",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "agent" : {
            "name" : "rum-js",
            "version" : "5.1.1"
          },
          "processor" : {
            "name" : "transaction",
            "event" : "transaction"
          },
          "labels" : {
            "label1" : "ahoi"
          },
          "observer" : {
            "hostname" : "c99d7caa67e7",
            "id" : "74cdd7ab-e3e5-4794-972d-cfd54f5f48d4",
            "ephemeral_id" : "bab410d0-501b-4a4e-93e8-0b1520992451",
            "type" : "apm-server",
            "version" : "7.6.2",
            "version_major" : 7
          },
          "trace" : {
            "id" : "59986f27506d0ab53a82f74f2669ff0a"
          },
          "@timestamp" : "2020-05-12T08:28:17.000Z",
          "ecs" : {
            "version" : "1.4.0"
          },
          "service" : {
            "name" : "test",
            "language" : {
              "name" : "javascript"
            }
          },
          "client" : {
            "ip" : "172.22.0.1"
          },
          "user" : {
            "name" : "mojovski",
            "id" : "aabbxx",
            "email" : "hi@mail.de"
          },
          "transaction" : {
            "duration" : {
              "us" : 425000
            },
            "custom" : {
              "campaign_name" : "campaign_1_welt.de_max-price:4eur",
              "stuff" : "stuff"
            },
            "name" : "Unknown",
            "marks" : {
              "agent" : {
                "domInteractive" : 301,
                "domComplete" : 416,
                "timeToFirstByte" : 35
              },
              "navigationTiming" : {
                "responseEnd" : 35,
                "responseStart" : 35,
                "domainLookupEnd" : 1,
                "domInteractive" : 301,
                "domContentLoadedEventStart" : 317,
                "domComplete" : 416,
                "domainLookupStart" : 1,
                "connectEnd" : 1,
                "connectStart" : 1,
                "loadEventStart" : 416,
                "requestStart" : 34,
                "fetchStart" : 0,
                "domContentLoadedEventEnd" : 342,
                "loadEventEnd" : 421,
                "domLoading" : 38
              }
            },
            "page" : {
              "referer" : "",
              "url" : "http://localhost:8080/"
            },
            "span_count" : {
              "started" : 23
            },
            "id" : "a6b27cdc0e2299b5",
            "type" : "page-load",
            "sampled" : true
          },
          "user_agent" : {
            "original" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0",
            "os" : {
              "name" : "Ubuntu"
            },
            "name" : "Firefox",
            "device" : {
              "name" : "Other"
            },
            "version" : "76.0."
          },
          "timestamp" : {
            "us" : 1589272097000246
          }
        }
      }
...
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the mapping of the index, read via
`GET apm-7.6.2-transaction-000001/_mapping`

(since the file is too large, I put it to gist: )

https://gist.github.com/mojovski/143fe5f87b54e2c020a3217ea55e3bbf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `match` query doesn't support wildcards.

You can try the `prefix` query instead if you're trying to search for prefixes.

```
GET apm-7.6.2-transaction-000001/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "prefix" : {                                       <-- change this
      "transaction.custom.campaign_name": "ca"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! Unfortunatelly, this is not working. probably because the field "transaction.custom.campaign_name" is available only in some data items? Would the query then look different?

Comment: No that should work either way. Can you update your question with the mapping of your index, please?

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question.  BTW, I also tried to add the field to the mapping via ```PUT apm-7.6.2-transaction-000001/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "transaction": {
      "properties":{
        "custom": {
          "properties":{
            "campaign_name":{"type":"text"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```

which did not help :(

Comment: My bad, I forgot to remove the `*` in the value... See my updated answer

Comment: thanks alot! But still not working :(( now I remember the reason, why I preferred to stay with SQL for so long time....

Comment: That's weird as I was able to reproduce the context and make it work with the above prefix query. As a side note, by comparing ES to SQL, you're comparing apples and oranges ;-)

Comment: I like oranges :)
ok, i tried to show all results, but to filter out hits where the field transaction.custom.campaign_name does not exists, and the result is empty:
```GET apm-7.6.2-transaction-000001/_search
{
    "query": {
        "exists": {
            "field": "transaction.custom.campaign_name"
        }
    }
}```
Might this indicate the issue? The field is not really "registered"?

Comment: Here you're actually asking for documents **that do have the field**, is this what you want?

Comment: Solved!! :D the issue was indeed, that I added the mapping AFTER the data was already in there. But the queries only apply on NEW data which came in after the field was added to the mapping. Now, new data can be search as you described.

Comment: Of course the mapping needs to be saved before indexing data. Glad you solved it!